# Ruby on rails accessing content of params hash in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to access the values stored in params hash from ApplicationController class directly.How can I do it? Foreaxmple:

```
 def setParams
 @parameters=params ???
 end
```

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: How can I access the values of params hash in application controller

Comment: just with `params[:key]`. Is that what you want ?

Comment: just post your params and tell what do you want to get from that?

Answer (score 0):

The univesal variable to get the ruby params is:

```
params
```

This will return the hash of parameters from the request that you can see in the server log.

To access it you just need to use:

```
def set_params #use ruby notation for methods which is underscore and _
 @parameters=params["key"]
end
```

Note that the key should be defined, as long as the incoming parameters for html view includes the codification: utf8, and the csrf token.

If you want to access to the full request:

```
def set_params
  @request = request
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :handle_params

  def handle_params
    my_param_key = params[:my_param_key]
  end
end
```

Hope this helps someone starting to code on ruby!